# What is the mass of carbon dioxide absorbed by an oak tree in one year?

Tags: botany, ecology, environment

I want to understand the environmental impact of oak trees due to absorption carbon dioxide. So my question is, what is the mass of carbon dioxide absorbed by an oak tree in one year?

Comment: What's the difference between '$CO2$' and '$\ce{CO2}$' ? I'm new to SE.

Comment: Oh ok, thank you. I have now proposed an edit using that format. Will that be for an equilibrium reaction with k1 and K2 as forward and backward rate constants?

Comment: Sometimes, the simple solutions work well: `CO<sub>2</sub>`.

Comment: It's uncommon (and probably not that useful) to consider this sort of question from a "per tree" perspective. "Per tree" depends greatly on the surrounding environment. Instead, people typically approach carbon fixation from a "per area" perspective.

Comment: I upvoted @RodrigodeAzevedo  comment, but neither work in titles on the phone and the Math thingy is unreadable. In any case one has always to ask oneself why not just writing carbon dioxide? It’s not as if there’s any equation involved. So it’s not justified. So I’ll edit it.

Comment: @trinitrotoluene: The difference is that some people (and I'm one of them) haven't memorized the keyboard combinations or other gymnastics needed to get subscripts :-)  Just about everyone will recognize what you mean if you write "CO2", though.

Comment: This question is unanswerable as it stands.  How big an oak tree, a year-old seedling or the centuries-old oaks of English forests?  What species?   Quercus robur (the English oak again) or the often shrubby Quercus wislizeni found in interior California?  Just to pick two of many species of oak.

Comment: @David I have posted a question regarding formatting on meta. Please let me know of the accepted formatting on Biology.SE

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Re: Bryan Krause's comment, measurements per hectare are common. However, if you can just estimate average trees per hectare, then it works out. But it still likely depends on the local climate, ecology etc. It also varies across the life term of the tree.

Some estimates have been made, such as in [this paper](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.488.4155&rep=rep1&type=pdf) (see Table 4), for *Quercus rubra* and 2 other hardwood species. They estimate that for the most mature trees, *Q. rubra* stores ~20 Mg/hectare total biomass, of which approximately half is carbon.

This is a little more than twice the biomass of the 8-year-old tree, so if we just linearly interpolate we could say that a hectare of oak stores ~1 Mg C per year. There are some problems with this- for example, older trees are likely to store much more than that, but it is not clear exactly how much variation there is over the course of an oak's life, and also there is likely variation between the sites in the study.

It is also clear that the other species measured, e.g. American chestnut, are more effective carbon sinks than oaks as young trees.

See the paper or this [pop science](https://www.scientificamerican.com/article/chestnut-tree-climate-change-carbon/) article on the subject for more information. THere are also a number of papers citing that paper that may be interesting, such as [this](https://academic.oup.com/forestry/article/87/1/129/602137), [this](https://www.mdpi.com/1999-4907/3/2/332), and [this](https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/abs/10.1111/gcb.14397).